# SAPUI5 - this.getView() is not a function

Tags: javascript, sapui5, getvalue

I am trying to get the input value, but when I call the function I get the error **this.getView() is not a function**

Below is the function in controller

```
    handleConfirmationMessageBoxPress: function(oEvent) {
        var bCompact = !!this.getView().$().closest(".sapUiSizeCompact").length;
        MessageBox.confirm(
            "Deseja confirmar a transferência?", {
                   icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.SUCCESS,
                   title: "Confirmar",
                    actions: [sap.m.MessageBox.Action.OK, sap.m.MessageBox.Action.CANCEL],
                    onClose: function(oAction) {
                      if (oAction == "OK"){
                          var loginA = this.getView().byId("multiInput").getValue();
                          alert(loginA)
                          MessageToast.show("Transferência efetuada");

                      }else{
                         // MessageToast.show("Transferência não cancelada");
                           }

                        },
                        styleClass: bCompact? "sapUiSizeCompact" : ""
            }
        );
    }
```

And here is the input in the view

```
   <m:Input id="multiInput" value="teste" placeholder="Clique no botão ao lado para buscar o usuário" showValueHelp="true" valueHelpRequest="valueHelpRequest" width="auto"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume that you get that error on the second `this.getView()` from inside the callback. You are getting this because of the way that `this` works in JavaScript. See the following MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

In a nutshell, calling a function freely without it being referenced from "inside" an object (i.e. `fnFunction()` vs `oObject.func()`), will cause the `this` to point to either nothing or the window object. To get the right `this`, you can either use the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) declaration, the [jQuery.proxy](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method or the [.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function:

```
onClose: oAction => {
   // your code
}

// OR

onClose: function(oAction) {
   // your code
}.bind(this)

// OR

onClose: jQuery.proxy(function(oAction) {
   // your code
}, this)
```